# How to design architecture for framework that supports different protocol

Tags: http, tcp, grpc, protocols

We are developing a framework using LabVIEW. We have separated the framework into the front end and back end and any communication protocols like gRPC, Rest APIs or TCP can be used. To achieve multiple protocol communication functionality, for each utility, we had to go with class architecture to override methods based on the communication protocol used.

For example, let’s take a calculator I have front-end UI, client, server, and backend. To support multiple protocols, the design comes as below.
[calculator_class_architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lyvmn.png)
Pros:

1. Scalable any other protocols
   Cons:
2. Large source code maintenance. Even for a simple calculator, we have 4 base class
   We would like to know if this is the right approach to switch between protocols or is there any other better approach to easily switch protocols
   Please add your thoughts. Thanks in advance

Comment: Architectural questions are discouraged (programming-specific questions are encouraged) on Stack overflow. Your question is likely to be downvotedclosed.

Comment: There are multiple out-of-the-box solutions for exposing gRPC APIs (services) as HTTP/JSON (~REST) endpoints. I encourage you to Google "grpc json transcoding". Envoy provides a [gRPC-JSON transcoder](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/grpc_json_transcoder_filter). There's also [gRPC Gateway](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway). Please review the alternative approaches before deciding on a path.